# php ?: operator syntax error (T_RETURN)

Tags: php

I get an error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN)

**Can i correct my code without IF statement?**

```
function isValid(){
    return false;
}
function foo(){
    isValid() ?: return false; //i dont want to return true yet!

    //another validations here that can return false
    isValid2() ?: return false;
    isValid3() ?: return false;

    return true;
}

var_dump(foo());
```

Comment: `return isValid() ? true : false;`

Comment: you have an if-statement, although it's the shortcut version. But why don't you just return the return of the function you're calling? `return isValid();`

Comment: `return !!isValid();`?  Or possibly even `return isValid();`!  Depending on whether `isValid()` *already* returns a boolean or not.

Comment: isValid() is just a first validation function

Answer (score 2):

Use

`return isValid() ? true : false;`

See [here](https://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators).

Comment: or just `return isValid();`

Comment: there are few validation functions and i dont want to rerurn true a this moment

Comment: @Steve that too, more elegant for sure. Just wanted to show a ternary operation to him.